Is 'were' used with 'ever' to express the impossibility of 'all the time' in if-clauses?
From Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.587.

Prosodic detachment is more likely and more appropriate for adjuncts
that are out of the positions their semantic type would normally
determine for them. Thus, for example, if a means adjunct were ever to
be in front position, or if a speech act-related adjunct were placed
in end position, prosodic detachment would be demanded:


ia. ?Statistically, we analysed it.  b.*Statistically we analysed it.
iia. ?Are you a spy, honestly?   b.*Are you a spy honestly?

Is 'a means adjunct' impossible to be in front position all the time, so 'were ever' is used ? Why not use the present tense-if a means adjunct is to be in front position, or if a speech act-related adjunct is placed in end position, prosodic detachment would be demanded. Does the author has other meaning by this different usage?

ever is just an intensifier, for a subjunctive usage. Compare If I were a rich man, which could be intensified to If I were ever to be a rich man. I don't know why we're more inclined to include to be if we've got ever, or why we never include it in If I were to be you, I'd do this. It (to be) doesn't really seem to mean anything here - it's just a kind of optional "verbal flourish".

@FumbleFingers Why does he use a subjunctive, but not a present tense? Does he mean 'a means adjunct' is less likely to be in the front position?

He uses subjunctive because according to formal grammar it should be subjunctive in such "hypothetical" contexts. As implied above, it's like If I were you I wouldn't do that (where If I was you... is colloquial, considered "uneducated" by some). Including ever doesn't necessarily imply the referent situation is less likely to arise than if "ever" wasn't (weren't! :) present (it's a "stylistic choice"). But ever certainly does imply that the referent situation occurs rarely, if ever.

...also note that If X were ever to happen... strongly implies that X has never happened yet.

Side issue: You are not using the phrase all the time idiomatically.  Instead of saying  "impossible to be in front position all the time" you should say  always impossible  or never possible.

@TimR Do you mean "always impossible to be in front position."?

@Mr.Wang I was trying to restate, idiomatically, the idea it seemed you were trying to convey with "impossible ... all the time".

The phrase were ever in conditional clauses headed by if is typically used with conditions being presented as unlikely but not impossible. The shift from simple "need" or "ever need" to "were ever to need" expresses the remoteness of the possibility.

If you were ever to need this car repaired (it's so well-made that we seriously doubt that will happen) just call the toll-free number and we will dispatch a fully certified mechanic.

So the inference one would draw from the original remark is that it would be somewhat unusual for a means adjunct to appear in front position.
Means adjuncts in front position are a stylistic choice, and prosodic detachment is a matter of degree.

Stealthily, the ninjas entered the fortified compound.

(One might argue there over whether stealthily is a means or manner adjunct.)

By boat, you can reach that area far more quickly than you can by truck. In places, mudslides have made the road nearly impassable.


What do you mean "and prosodic detachment is a matter of degree."?

In a grammatical context, prosody refers to the intonations, rhythms and pauses in speech that isolate syntactic constituents. Those prosodic elements can be combined in various ways, and thus there is considerable nuance in how the "detachment" is realized in speech.  In a textual representation of speech the detachment is represented, relatively crudely, with a few simple punctuation marks.
